# How do I use tensors with MathJax?

Tags: javascript, html, latex, mathjax

I am new to HTML and am trying to transfer a load of LaTeX documents over to the new format. So far so good with most of the mathematics using MathJax but tensors seem to be a harder problem. Is there an easy way of implementing them? Even if it is a bit of a cheap hack.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--MathJax-->
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
<!--LaTeX commands-->
$ \newcommand{\pd}[2]{ \frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$
</head>
<body>
<p>I would like this to come out well:
    $\tensor{\Lambda}{^\nu_\mu^{\gamma\beta}} $</p>
<p>I imagine it isn't as simple as defining a new command like I've done for partial differentiation:
    $\pd{y}{x}$.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should describe what \tensor does. E.g., you could link to some documentation on CTAN.

Comment: Thanks, will do. I would like to recreate the macro '\tensor' as found in the LaTeX [tensor package](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tensor/tensor.pdf)

Comment: In the core extensions, there's `\sideset` from AMSmath to create preceding sub/supscripts. Otherwise, you'd have to write an extension that matches the tensor package (since the internal format is basically MathML which has a multiscripts element).